# "Run once" massive amounts of data to insert... Local VS Network connection?

Tags: .net, sql-server, optimization, entity-framework-4

So I have this one time deal where I have to get data from different databases/tables, slice and dice it and insert it into one single table.

This is done through a Windows Form C# .NET 4.0 application.

I have to run this one time deal process once (obviously) for each different entities we'll be using in our CRM environment.

For some entities, only 20,000 rows to insert so a networked SQL connection is just fine.

But this other one is 800,000 long and is taking quite a long time to finish.

I was wondering whether I'd gain any speed by installing the application on the SQL Server itself and specifying a local connection in my connection string instead of a networked one.

I'd have to make formal request to gain remote desktop access to that server, which is why I'm asking if anyone else has ever used that approach successfully here before actually testing it.

Also, I'm doing my inserts through Entity Framework 4's `SaveChanges()` which I call at each inserted row. Perhaps, there is room for optimization there as well and I'm willing to read your opinions.

Thanks much!

Comment: Entity Framework is not well suited for bulk operations (like inserting 800'000 rows). And if you insist on using it - then yes, it would be beneficial if you'd insert a batch of rows (500, 1000, 2500 - you need to experiment here a bit) and then call `.SaveChanges()` only once, on that batch. Calling it for every single row will **significantly** slow you down!

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. This is an ETL. SSIS was specifically built for ETL. You'll waste alot of development time by not taking advantage of SSIS's productivity boosting / already built in features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anytime you can eliminate the network you will see a performance improvement. For 800k rows, I would use the SqlBulkCopy class. It's very easy to use, it basically does the equivalent of a BULK INSERT under the covers.

Comment: I think I'll implement some kind of bulk insert within my EF repository.

Answer (score 1):

Unless all the databases/tables are are on the same server there is not a lot to be gained.  If you performed the inserts on the same physical box yes that would increase insert speed but you still have network in the reads.

Inserting one row at a time is the slowest insert local or remote.

Look at SqlBulkCopy (+1 Philip), TVP, or Drapper to optimize insert.

Slice and dice?  How complex is this?  Does it required .NET?  Can this be done with TSQL?

Comment: Yes, I need to do some regexp work and connect to different CRM environments to fetch GUIDs and such.

Comment: Could look at CLR integration on the SQL box.  But for a one time thing probably not worth the hassle.